# How can I set/fake the proptype of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to write a shorthand version of antd's Select/Option

Instead of using

```
<Option value='foo'>bar</Option>
```

I want to use

```
<Option value='foo' label='bar' />
```

I wrote following wrapper code:

```
import { Select } from 'antd'

const Option = (options) => {
  const label = options.label
  delete options.label

  return <Select.Option {...options}>{label}</Select.Option>
}
```

When I use it in following example

```
<Select>
  <Option value='foo' label='bar'
</Select>
```

I get

**Warning: the children of `Select` should be `Select.Option` or `Select.OptGroup`, instead of `Option`.**

How can I return my component in a way that antd thinks it is an original `Select.Option`?

Comment: Instead of creating your own component, you could write `<Option value='foo' children='bar' />` on the original component instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to how [original component](https://github.com/react-component/select/blob/master/src/Select.tsx) works, `Option` component is dummy component that is never rendered and used as a placeholder for `Select` data, wrapping it with another component doesn't do any good.

A possible solution should extend `Select` instead:

```
import {Select as OriginalSelect} from 'antd';

const Option = props => null;

const Select = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  children = React.Children(children).map(child => {
    if (child.type === Option) {
      const {label, ...props} = child.props;
      return <OriginalSelect.Option {...props}>{label}</OriginalSelect.Option>;
    } else {
      return child;
    }
  });

  return <OriginalSelect {...props}>{children}</OriginalSelect>;
};
```

Also, `<Option value='foo' label='bar' />` cannot be considered a shortcut for `<Option value='foo'>bar</Option>` because it's of the same length, so if the only purpose of `Option` wrapper is to make the code shorter, it's redundant.